# iOS: Text disappearing from subclassed UITextfield when responder resigns

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitextfield

I am experiencing issues where the text I have input into a UITextField is disappearing whenever it is resigned as the first responder. When you tap back into the text field, the text re-appears. The UITextField subclass has nothing in it apart from a slight rounding to the corners. I will be adding more at a later date. Has anyone experienced issues like this before?

Here is my code. Like I said there is nothing in this subclass apart from the rounding of the corners. I will be putting code to add padding to the textfield later.

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class EVTextField: UITextField
{
  override func layoutSubviews()
  {
    layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
  }
}
```

**Step by step guide to replicate**

1. Tap on UITextField.
2. Enter text.
3. Either dismiss keyboard or tap into next UITextField.
4. Text seems to disappear in previously resigned UItextField.

**Video Example**
[image: Weirdtextfield]

Comment: As i can see the text stays there but, probably its text color after didendediting of uitextfield ?

Comment: @Aragunz No the colour is still black, I have checked when debugging the view hierarchy

Comment: show text field delegate code?people can understand

Comment: In the image above it looks like TEst and yyyy are there when u switch textfields ?

Comment: @Aragunz Yes, when I switch back to the textfield the text re-appears which is fine. But it disappears when I resign the responder of that textfield

Comment: @karthikeyan there is no custom delegate code, I haven't changed anything from the default implementation.

Comment: So text is there, only it changes color to white or it hides when resigning first responder somehow

Comment: @Aragunz Yes that's what seems to be happening, but I can guarantee that the text colour is not white

Comment: Is that white background behind the text field or is that white background **in front** of the text field? You will have to share more information because there are many many possibilities how this could happen.

Comment: @Sulthan the white background is the `backgroundColor` of the UITextField

Comment: @RhuariGlen, i can't guess what is wrong without of your code

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Code has been added, like I said though, there isn't anything in it that would cause this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, I had forgotten to call `super.layoutSubviews()` when rounding the corners of my UITextFields. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if (self.emailTextField.isFirstResponder) {
    [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

if (self.passwordTextField.isFirstResponder) {
    [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: on the texfield did begin editing or something like that, the delegate on your class which contains the fields.